# Brand new Laravel 8 installation: "/admin" route redirects to "/" for no apparent reason

Tags: php, laravel

I originally created a new Laravel 8 project, made some adjustments and then had this issue where going to '/admin' just redirects the URL back to '/', where as '/admin/' went where I expected it to, despite the routing.

But now in testing I have just done a brand new fresh Laravel 8 install, and I haven't changed a single thing. Yet I still get the same issue where '/admin' specifically, gets redirected to '/' home.

Just to clarify, going to another random path like '/test' gives a 404 as expected, so its just admin. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening like this?

Comment: hm, that's weird. It must be a minor mistake for sure. At the routes can you do: `'prefix' => '/admin'`

Comment: Also remove this: `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});`

Comment: Could it be something odd in your middleware?

Comment: @workservice yeah really strange. I have removed the '/' route like you said, and tried the pre slash on the '/admin' prefix too. But going to 'admin' still just redirects to '/' (I can see in the URL)

Comment: Can you do php artisan route:clear

Comment: Yep I have tried that. Infact!! I just did a brand new fresh installation of laravel 8 without changing absolutely anything, and when going to "/admin" it still redirects me to "/"???? But going to say '/test' is fine it just 404's.... something really weird here

Comment: maybe can be some configuration in the .htaccess (not just within the laravel project but also on a root folder level)... or some configuration in your host or virtual host.

Comment: The .htaccess is default with the Larvael 8 install, and I am just using "php artisan serve" to run the site. Just so strange